# Event for Citrix Profile Management Printer-Mappings

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-printers, xenapp, xendesktop, terminal-server

Is there some event (eventlog) or another source of information to find out when the Citrix profile management is done with mapping network printers?

It would also be great to know when it is done mapping those printers installed on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Application windows event viewer. Specifically eventid 1103 and 1104. It will tell you what's (and what's not) mapped from the client.